# Maximizing the Number of Cyclic Quadrilaterals in the Plane Given $8$ Points

Tags: geometry

How do you arrange $8$ points in the $x-y$ plane so that the number of cyclic quadrilaterals whose 4 vertices are all in the set of $n$ points and whose circumcircles are distinct is maximized?

I feel like you would have to make them into a grid because then you form squares, rectangles, isosceles trapezoids, and maybe even kites. The only possible grid would be $2$ by $4$. This gives $8$ total cyclic quadrilaterals with distinct circumcircles ($3$ $1x1$ squares, $2$ $1x2$ rectangles, $1$ $1x3$ rectangle, and $2$ isosceles trapezoids).

Can anybody think of a better configuration?

Comment: Because three points define a circle, you are potentially looking at subsets of the set of eight points which mutually intersect in at most two places. Then which of these configurations can be realised geometrically with circles.

Comment: I thought about that approach. Because $3$ points determine a circle, there can be at most $\dbinom{8}{3} = 56$ circles. However, each circle passes through $4$ points and there are $\dbinom{4}{3} = 4$ ways to choose $3$ points on each quadrilateral, leaving a maximum of $\frac{56}{4} = 14$ circles. So, I have a pretty good upper bound. I'm just pretty sure that the number can be increased from $8$.

Comment: A cube achieves $12$ circles in three dimensions, and Oscar's answer achieves $12$ if straight lines are counted as circles. So you won't get below $12$ by general arguments - if the maximum is below $12$ the constraint on planarity has to come in.

Comment: To get to $14$ choose the sets $1234; 1256; 1278; 1735; 1746;; 2835; 2846; 7834; 7856; 3456$ (these are the ten you get from a numbering of Oscar's diagram from top to bottom) then the diagonals $1368$ and $2457$ (which can be realised as circles in three dimensions - think cube) and finally $1458; 2367$ which in the cube configuration are the inscribed tetrahedra and are non-planar.

Comment: @MarkBennet I think the problem is just talking about planar circles. After getting these $10$ circles, how do you actually prove that $12$ cannot be reached? Why can't the other two rectangles from the cube somehow be transposed onto the plane in order to get $12$?

Comment: Your statement of the problem is confusing. You say "Given a set of $8$ points", but that implies that the points are specified in advance. Better is just "How do you arrange $8$ points in the $x$-$y$ plane so that...".

Comment: Yes - I took it to be planar circles. What I am suggesting is that to get below $12$ and prove eg $10$ planarity will have to be part of the proof because you can get $12$ in three dimensions.

Comment: I think you can probably argue that the convex hull of the points makes a circle and then you have an inner circle, and maybe the ordering of the points on the two circles means that you lose at least two of the possible fourteen. I think Oscar's method will yield $12$ in the end because the two lines can be transformed to circles whilst preserving the existing circles.

Comment: Like several other questions you've asked, this is a problem from the [2021 Mathcamp qualifying quiz](https://www.mathcamp.org/qualifying_quiz/current_quiz/), due March 18th. Posting it here is a violation of the MSE ["Contest problem" policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy), and also against the rules for the Mathcamp application.